# Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas, shared-access-signatures

I am trying to create an Azure SAS to a blob. However, I am getting authentication failed error. Whatever I try, I am not able to construct a well formed stringToSign or signiture.

The error says:

**"Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl 2021-03-11T08:08:46Z 2021-03-12T08:08:46Z /blob/{myAccountName}/quickstartcontainer/sampleFile2813061026464365578.txt 2020-02-10 b "**

My stringToSign is :

```
    String stringToSign= "rl\n"+ 
                         "2021-03-11T08:08:46Z" +"\n" + 
                         "2021-03-12T08:08:46Z"+ "\n"+ 
                         "\n"+ 
                         "\n"+ 
                         "\n"+ 
                         "\n"+ 
                         2020-02-10"+ 
                         "\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";
     String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);
```

My SAS token uri is :

```
      String sasToken = "?sp=rl"
                        + "&st=" +  "2021-03-11T08:08:46Z" 
                        + "&se=" +  "2021-03-12T08:08:46Z"
                        + "&sv=" +  "2020-02-10"
                        + "&sr=b"
                        + "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");
```

The encryption function is:

```
  public static String computeHMac256(final String base64Key, final String stringToSign) {
        try {
            byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Key);
            Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            hmacSHA256.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256"));
            byte[] utf8Bytes = stringToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSHA256.doFinal(utf8Bytes));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

How can I generate a well formed signiture for my sas uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the instructions provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#constructing-the-signature-string), your `stringToSign` should conform to the following structure:

```
StringToSign = signedPermissions + "\n" +  
               signedStart + "\n" +  
               signedExpiry + "\n" +  
               canonicalizedResource + "\n" +  
               signedIdentifier + "\n" +  
               signedIP + "\n" +  
               signedProtocol + "\n" +  
               signedVersion + "\n" +  
               signedResource + "\n"
               signedSnapshotTime + "\n" +
               rscc + "\n" +  
               rscd + "\n" +  
               rsce + "\n" +  
               rscl + "\n" +  
               rsct
```

Which is not the same as what you're doing. Essentially you're missing `canonicalizedResource` and `signedResource` parameters.

Please form your `stringToSign` properly and you should not get the error you're encountering. I think it should be something like (not tested though):

```
String stringToSign= "rl\n"+ 
                     "2021-03-11T08:08:46Z" +"\n" + 
                     "2021-03-12T08:08:46Z"+ "\n"+ 
                     "/blob/{myAccountName}/quickstartcontainer/sampleFile2813061026464365578.txt 2020-02-10\n"+ 
                     "\n"+ 
                     "\n"+ 
                     "\n"+ 
                     2020-02-10"+"\n"+ 
                     "b\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";
```

Comment: The last version of my stringToSign is here and it works!!!. Thank you. String stringToSign= "rl\n"+ start +"\n" + expiry+ "\n"+ "/blob/"+accountName+"/quickstartcontainer/sampleFile2813061026464365578.txt\n"+ "\n"+ "\n"+ "\n"+ azureApiVersion+"\n"+ "b\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n";